# Is it possible to edit a Here document after creating it?

Tags: ruby, heredoc

If I create a Here document:

```
myheredoc = <<HTMLOUTPUT
<div>This is the div</div>
HTMLOUTPUT
```

Can I use 'myheredoc' to manipulate this Here document like a regular string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure can. The syntax is there to make it easier to read, you are still just creating a string.

```
>> myheredoc = <<HTMLOUTPUT
<div>This is the div</div>
HTMLOUTPUT
=> "<div>This is the div</div>\n"
>> myheredoc << "<p>some paragraph</p>"
=> "<div>This is the div</div>\n<p>some paragraph</p>"
```

Answer (score 3):

heredoc is just a syntax for generating a string.  Therefore you can use all standard string methods.  eg:

```
replaceddoc = myheredoc.gsub(/div/, 'replaced div')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of declaring strings:

- Unescaped: 'foo' or %q[foo] or here-doc style <<MARKER
- Escaped: "foo" or %Q[foo] or here-doc style <<"MARKER"

In all cases the strings are editable, not frozen, so yes, they can be modified after the fact.